# Difference between making query string and serialize method

Tags: jquery

There are two ways to send the form data through ajax:

1. making query string manually and passed it as ajax posted data. for e.g.

   ```
   $.ajax(function(){
       type: 'post',
       data:"val1="+$("#input1").val()+"&val2="+$("#input1").val(),
       .....
   });
   ```
2. Use $('#myForm').serialize() method for e.g.

   ```
   $.ajax(function(){       
       type: 'post',
       data:$("#myForm").serialize(),
       .....
   });
   ```

What is the key difference between sending the form data through these two ways.

Comment: That I already know that using serialize() method all the form data will be sent to the method. :)

Comment: How we can pass "#" and "&" character while making the query string using these ways?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The .serialize() method creates a text string in standard URL-encoded notation. It operates on a jQuery object representing a set of form elements. The form elements can be of several types:

```
<form>
<div><input type="text" name="a" value="1" id="a" /></div>
<div><input type="text" name="b" value="2" id="b" /></div>
<div><input type="hidden" name="c" value="3" id="c" /></div>
<div>
<textarea name="d" rows="8" cols="40">4</textarea>
</div>
<div><select name="e">
<option value="5" selected="selected">5</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
<option value="7">7</option>
</select></div>
<div>
<input type="checkbox" name="f" value="8" id="f" />
</div>
<div>
<input type="submit" name="g" value="Submit" id="g" />
</div>
</form>
```

The .serialize() method can act on a jQuery object that has selected individual form elements, such as , , and . However, it is typically easier to select the  tag itself for serialization:

```
$('form').submit(function() {
alert($(this).serialize());
return false;
});
```

This produces a standard-looking query string:

```
a=1&b=2&c=3&d=4&e=5
```

Comment: Suppose my one hidden variable contain "#" character then what will happen with serialize method and how it will look like the query string?

Answer (score 2):

Serialize will urlencode your data. Furthermore, it will iterate over all your form elements. Manually making a query string requires you to do this manually. Its a good shortcut :)

Comment: Thank for your answer, Do you have any proof of this statement. I mean to say is there any kind of example available online?

Comment: How about the documentation for the JQuery serialize method? http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Comment: Actually this question was asked to me in an Interview, I gave them all the valid answer but they need the key difference. Thats what I want to know about. By the way, Thanks Jeremy

Comment: @ArunJain That is the 'key difference' really. The urlencoding bit.

Answer (score 2):

[Jquery serialize()](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) method creates a text string in standard URL-encoded notation. This link might work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Key difference is the $("#myForm").serialize() escapes the symbols. It makes url encode

Comment: Sometimes I use to make query string but if it contain "#" character. Then the form data is not supposed to be submitted due to invalid data error. But if I use serialize() method will it not be happened?

Answer (score -1):

They Essentially do the same thing.
`$("#myForm").serialize()` is a bit cleaner and you know that if the name changes eg if `<input type="text" name="val" value="1" id="a" />` changes to `<input type="text" name="val2" value="1" id="a" />` then it will pick it up and the data field will be "val2=1". but if you using the manual string building then it would still be "val=1". so not much difference. if you want to validate the forms then the first option might be better.